# Reduce duplicate of code in ActionResult with HTTP

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, actionresult, modelstate

Goal:
Reduce the duplicate of code in relation to Actionresult with HTTP.

Problem:
I have two actionresult with Actionresult (with HTTP) that has same source code that is dublicate of code.

> How should I enable to use the code "ModelState.AddmodelError" for
>   both actionresult in this context without having dublicate of code?

Info:
*Please remember this this code is a simple sample of the big project.
*Im using asp.net mvc 4
*Today Im refactoring a source code in order to have less dublicate of code.
*The reason of having two different actions is a long story but right now Im doing refactoring

Today's source code:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(AddUserVM model)  
    {
        if(model.FirstName == model.LastName)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("LastName", "The last name cannot be the same as the first name.");
        }
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add_dd(AddUserVM model)  
{
    if(model.FirstName == model.LastName)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("LastName", "The last name cannot be the same as the first name.");
    }
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

---

```
Proposal that is might not working:

public ActionResult Add(AddUserVM model)  
{
    model = Test1(model);

    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add_dd(AddUserVM model)  
{
    model = Test1(model);

    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

private model Test1(AddUserVM model)
{

    if(model.FirstName == model.LastName)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("LastName", "The last name cannot be the same as the first name.");
    }

    return ""
}
```

---

```
public class AddUserVM  
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Use a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[NotEqualTo]` or similar validation attribute so you get both client and server side validation

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ModelState You can use ViewBag or ViewData for remove duplication.

```
    public ActionResult Add(AddUserVM model)  
    {
       model = Test1(model);

      if(!ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        return View(model);
      }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Add_dd(AddUserVM model)  
     {
        Test1(model);

        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
         }

       return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

private void Test1(AddUserVM model)
{

    if(model.FirstName == model.LastName)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage ="The last name cannot be the same as the first name.";
    }    

}
```